# R. Big Query. Replace SQL with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery

I have code that works well, looks like:

```
sql <- paste0("
SELECT
  date
  , dimension2
  , landingPagePath
  , source
  , medium
  , campaign
  , keyword
  , adContent
FROM
  `project_id.google_analytics.ga_cid_sessions`
WHERE 
  DATE(date) > cast('"
  , today()-30
  ,"' as date)
")
table_bq_cid_sessions <- bq_project_query(bq_project, sql)
bq_cid_sessions <- bq_table_download(table_bq_cid_sessions)
```

I wish to replace it with dplyr and try:

```
bq_cid_sessions <- select(
  bq_tbl_ga_cid_sessions
  , c(date, dimension2)
  ) %>% 
  filter(date >=  today()-30) %>%
  collect()
```

but have error:

```
Ошибка: Job 'project_id.job_xxxxxxxxxxx.US' failed
x No matching signature for operator - for argument types: DATE, FLOAT64. Supported signatures: INT64 - INT64; NUMERIC - NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC - BIGNUMERIC; FLOAT64 - FLOAT64; DATE - INT64; DATE - DATE; TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP; DATETIME - DATETIME; TIME - TIME; TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL; DATE - INTERVAL; DATETIME - INTERVAL; INTERVAL - INTERVAL at [4:28] [invalidQuery]
```

What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like `today()-30` is returning a FLOAT64. Is that `lubridate::today()`? Does it resolve if you use `filter(date >=  as.Date(today())-30) %>%`?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. I used `lubridate::today()` and I checked that `today()-30` returns a DATE. I'm using `lubridate_1.8.0` and `R version 4.1.1`. What version of R and lubridate are you using?

Comment: @JonSpring, sorry yes it`s lubridate.

@RiccoD, same versions of package and R.
I see now, that have date as STRING in BigQuery.
How I can transform it while select with dplyr?

Comment: Perhaps `filter(as.Date(date) >=  today()-30)`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment about `today()-30` is working, it is incorrect because when I tested it I converted my BQ table to a dataframe that's why it worked.

To correct my testing I now used `tbl(my_bq_connection, "table_name")`. To be able to properly compare dates calculation, `today()-30` should not be included in the `select()`. BigQuery interprets this as DATE - FLOAT hence the error. A workaround for this is to move out the `today()-30` and use result of `today()-30` in `select()`.  Cast to DATE both `date` and result to make sure that both are in DATE type.

For testing I used this table:

[image]

See R code:

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

projectid<-"project-id"
datasetid<-"dataset"
bq_conn <- dbConnect(bigquery(),
project = projectid,
dataset = datasetid,
use_legacy_sql = FALSE)

test_tb <-tbl(bq_conn, "test_1")
com_date <- today() - 30
test_query <- select(test_tb,c(date,B2)) %>% filter(as.Date(date) >= as.Date(com_date))
test_query
```

Generated query in BQ (seen in Query History):

[image]

Output in R:

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: BigQueryConnection
  date          B2
  <chr>      <int>
1 2021-09-30   165
```

Comment: It works! Great, thank you

Comment: @АндрейБуланкин you can mark it as answered so this can be a reference to other people who encounter the same problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have not enough reputation =\

Comment: @АндрейБуланкин you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check icon on the left side of the answer.